# Can't specify URL for Bonita soft behind apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat, reverse-proxy, bonita

I've got a bonita portal application running in a Tomcat environment behind an apache reverse proxy (2.4).

My current config in my virtualhost is working fine for url like https://www.mybonita.com/bonita/:

```
ProxyPass         /bonita  http://localhost:8080/bonita
ProxyPassReverse  /bonita  http://localhost:8080/bonita
```

What I would like to do now is to make it works with a url like: 
https://www.mybonita.com/ or at least https://www.mybonita.com/myapp/

I did this new configuration

```
ProxyPass         /myapp http://localhost:8080/bonita
ProxyPassReverse  /myapp http://localhost:8080/bonita
```

But it gives me "The requested URL /bonita/ was not found on this server."

So I modified to:

```
    ProxyPass         /myapp/  http://localhost:8080/bonita/
    ProxyPassReverse  /myapp/  http://localhost:8080/bonita/
```

That was better, I could see the login page, but the url is like:
https://www.mybonita.com/bonita/login.jsp?redirectUrl=%2Fbonita%2Fportal%2Fhomepage
and then when I want to login, I have a 404 error page....

Then, I tried to add this line

```
ProxyPassReverse  /myapp  /bonita
```

It seemed at first better (no more 404 errors... a url without 'bonita' anymore in it)...
but I can't login... The page comes always to the login page with no particular error message...

So, what would be a correct configuration to have a Bonita portal working behind an apache reverse proxy with a personalized URL?

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^(?!/bonita)(.*)$"  "/bonita$1" [R,L]
RewriteRule    "^/(.*)"  "http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1" [P]
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
```